# JAVA obfuscator

Tags: java, eclipse, obfuscation

Looking for good Java obfuscator utility that can obfuscate both complete application (the final output) and jar files. Commercial or open source.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define 'good'?

Comment: Obfuscators are rarely worth the trouble. But if you want to waste money, or if you're in the very few cases where it can make sense, I won't stop you. However, you need to [tell us more about what you want it for](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), so that we can choose between the many possibilities. What assets do you want to protect? What platform will the code run on?

Answer (score 1):

**[proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)** is a good Java obfuscator.

- It's free
- Works with .class files, and full .jar files
- Easy to use
- Use in command line, or a GUI